# Proving $(f^{-1}(x))'\cdot f'(f^{-1}(x))\equiv 1$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inverse-function

I was playing around with an integral formula I came across recently:
$$\int g'(x)f(g(x))f'(g(x))dx=\frac12f^2(g(x))+C$$
I decided to try $g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ to see what happens.

Note I'm assuming inverses and differentials exist for the function

It gives: $$\int (f^{-1}(x))'\cdot x\cdot f'(f^{-1}(x)) dx=\frac12f^2(f^{-1}(x))+C=\frac{x^2}{2}+C$$
But, $$\int x dx =\frac{x^2}{2}+C$$ so this implies that the rest of the integrand is equivalent to $1$, but I can't seem to find a way to show that fact directly, without the use of the integral formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have
$$
 f(f^{-1}(x))= x 
$$
for all $x$ where the inverse function is defined. Differentiating this identity with respect to $x$ and using the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) gives
$$
(f^{-1}(x))'\cdot f'(f^{-1}(x))= 1\, .
$$
(This is how the rule for [differentiating an inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation) is usually proved.)

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you, I should've thought of it.

Answer (score 4):

Let $g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$
$$\Rightarrow f(g(x))=f(f^{-1}(x))=x$$
Differentiating both side w.r.t x we get
$$f'(g(x)).g'(x)=1$$
$$\Rightarrow f'(f^{-1}(x)).(f^{-1}(x))'=1$$

Answer (score 2):

$(f^{-1}(x))'=\frac 1 {f'(f^{-1}(x))}$  (assuming that $f$ is differentiable and $f'(f^{-1}(x)) \neq 0$) and this formula can be found in  almost any Calculus text.

Proof: Just differentiate $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ using Chain Rule.

Comment: Strangely, I've never seen it before, but nevertheless, I requested assistance in *proving* the statement. I already know it is true.

Comment: @RhysHughes OK. I just added a proof.